# jQuery-chosen plugin: not listening for touch event in iPad

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using jQuery-chosen plugin for multi-select drop down, everything is working fine with desktop, but in iPad when i tried to deselect the selected option through touch(mouse click event is working fine), it is not listening for touch event(though i have written "touchend" event).

which event should i use to make this work?

Comment: Can you show examples from your code, screenshots, anything?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwhr5B_lk7LtUlFfMkpkTTI2cDA/view - here u can see the screenshot Said Kholov , problem is when i click of cross mark on any one of those it is working but on touch is not working

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Chosen plugin actually has this bug.

Tested this code in console http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/
It works

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("search-choice-close");
//search-choice-close is class of X button.
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
       this.parentNode.remove()
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: I didn't check that yet @Said Kholov, I don't have iPad with me right now, Tomorrow I'll check it and let you know. :)

Comment: you can test it in your browser. There is a device emulator in chrome for sure.

Comment: Why are you using for loop there? @Siad Kholov

Comment: It return several items with "search-choice-close" class

Comment: Yeah, got it @Said Kolov, I don't even have code with me to check it right now. I'll check it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Said Kholov's answer will work for the existing tags but not newly created tags. You can try this: (not efficient but works)

```
 //Fix the remove item on touch devices
if (Modernizr && Modernizr.touch) {
    $('.chosen-choices').on('touchend', '.search-choice-close', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $select = $this.closest('.chosen-container').prev('select');
        var toRemove = $.trim($this.parent().text());
        var vals = $select.val();
        vals = $.grep(vals, function(value) {
            return $.trim(value).trim() !== toRemove;
        });
        $select.val(vals).trigger('chosen:updated');
   });
}
```

Comment: without Modernizr, it should work right @Aamir Afridi?

Comment: You can use jQuery or native js to detect touch devices. Google for "detect touch device javascript"

Comment: Have to modify a bit to make sure it works for multiple instances of this. This applied only to the first multiple select box... I'll find a work around for this.

Comment: Actually this solution does not work if the value="" of the option does NOT match the text displayed within it, which is often the case.

Comment: hmmm. if you find the solution, please update the answer

Answer (score 1):

The simplest most elegant way to solve this is to just trigger a CLICK event from the TOUCH event using [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).

```
$.getScript('/js/modernizr-custom.js', function() {

    if (Modernizr && Modernizr.touchevents) {
        $('.chosen-choices').on('touchend', '.search-choice-close', function(){
            $(this).trigger('click');
       });  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 problems 1- remove button not worked 2- when you click to add the menu not opened after adding the first item:

Just hack it using:

1- add listener to check when your dropdown changed :

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen().change(updateChosen);
```

2- create function like i did to handle it :

```
function updateChosen(){
        $(".search-choice-close").on("touchend", function () {
        $(this).trigger("click");
    });
    //Open Menu again 
    $(".chosen-choices").on("touchend", function(){
        $(this).find(".chosen-search-input").blur().focus();
    });
}
```

Happy hacking Day :)